# adding / configuring taskqueue's - Reservation Activity and Assignment Activity

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm trying to follow the directions at https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/quickstart/php/setup-add-task-queues and it says to set the "Reservation Activity" to "Reserved" and the "Assignment Activity" to "Busy".

Only problem: those aren't available options. The only two options I have are the same for both: Offline and Unavailable.

So what should I set those fields to? Do I need to do additional configuring not mentioned in the tutorial to get Reserved and Busy as options? Or maybe the tutorial is out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the issue is that the default Activities have changed since that tutorial was written.

Per https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/quickstart/php/setup-understanding-activities the default activities were, at the time that the tutorial was written (per the screenshot):

- Offline (Unavailable)
- Idle (Available)
- Busy (Unavailable)
- Reserved (Unavailable)

The defaults, now, however, are different. Quoting https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/activity, "*TaskRouter pre-populates new Workspaces with "Offline", "Unavailable", and "Available" Activities*".

So I guess if you want to work through that out-of-date tutorial you'll need to add new activities or just set "Reservation Activity" and "Assignment Activity" both to "Unavailable" since those both have Availability set to false per the screenshot in the first link.